# Store macro's in powerpoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I've created some macro's for my powerpoint file. Problem now is that I can only use them for that particular powerpoint. Does anybody know how I can create a some kind of personal macro workbook in powerpoint / Word (like the one you have in excel)?

Comment: Some simple ideas: A) For MS Word you can use `Normal template` or any other base template you use for your documents. B) In MS PowerPoint you could: 1. create add-in, 2. set `add-in open event` to open any other presentation where you will store all you macros.

Comment: KazJaw: of course, to set an add-in open event to open the presentation where you'll store macros, you'd need yet another add-in, so it might be simplest just to do the add-in.  However, doing it the way you describe would make it simpler to modify your macros or add new ones.  One could always just put the macros in a separate PPTM file and open it when the macros are needed.

Answer (score 0):

> No such equivalent to the Excel Personal Macro workbook in PowerPoint.

Take a look at http://skp.mvps.org/ppafaq.htm.  You need to save your pptm file as an add-in (ppam).

Once saved as an add-in, you need to load it via File > PowerPoint Options > Add-ins > Manage: Add-ins > Go (at the bottom).  Then Browse.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Good Discussion on the question  - http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-powerpoint/how-do-you-save-macro-to-personal-module-in-pp/4b964ca5-9ef9-45bc-aa2a-a01f9cceb3cd?auth=1